# Servidor imagenes

Tags: html

Para poder subir una imagen en Html hay que usar un servidor o una nube algo así por el estilo no ? Ahora mismo estoy haciendo una pagina web las imágenes están en mi pc tengo entendido que al publicar las imágenes no aparecerían. Que servidor o nube puedo utilizar para eso. Gracias

Comment: hola, si es una pagina estatica nada mas sin interaccion con data puedes alojarla en github pages que usaria el propio codigo del repo.

Comment: Puedes subirla a cualquier repositorio de imágenes y poner el link en tu código y listo. Pueda que esta pregunta termine cerrada ya que no hay un problema especifico que tratar. Recuerda leer [ask]

Comment: Si son imágenes estáticas normalmente puedes subir las imágenes al mismo sitio que estés subiendo tu html, a no ser que tengas gigas de imágenes, cualquier alojamiento que tengas para tu html/css/js debería permitirte subir los asset estáticos (imágenes, fuentes..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a **subirla a internet**, para mostrar imágenes en tu página web necesitas un **hosting**, es decir, servicio de alojamiento web que te permita subir todos los archivos y tus imágenes, y le da una URL a cada archivo, incluso a las imágenes.

Si estás **en tu ordenador y no vas a subir tu código a internet**, necesitas un **servidor local como Wamp y XAMPP**. Son útiles para el desarrollo en tu propio ordenador, pero cuando desees que tu sitio web esté disponible en línea, necesitarás un hosting para alojar los archivos de tu página web.

Puedes **descargar Wamp o Xampp en estos enlaces**, elige el que te parezca más fácil o más cómodo de usar:

[Descarga Wamp](https://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[Descarga Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html)